# Derive the centroid of an area from a limiting procedure

Tags: geometry

I wondered if the centroid of an area could be derived as a limit from the centroid of the solid of revolution built by the same area revolving around an axis of revolution.

e.g.: the [volume centroid of a spherical wedge](http://books.google.it/books?id=PUVvwfjhjvMC&pg=PA430&lpg=PA430&dq=Spherical%20wedge%20Centroid&source=bl&ots=53AtS8NynV&sig=KgcMqei4vDoPX1gs3yMU-cfng-o&hl=en&sa=X&ei=_BTUUYbnAYeM4gS5oYHoCA&ved=0CCwQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=Spherical%20wedge%20Centroid&f=true) is $C_{V} = \frac{3\pi}{16}r\frac{\sin[\theta]}{\theta}$, where $r$ is the radius of the sphere and $\theta$ is the dihedral angle. The [centroid of a semicircular lamina](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Semicircle.html) is $C_{A} = \frac{4r}{3\pi}$

Now I tought it was possible a limit procedure like
$\lim\limits_{\theta\to 0} C_{V}$=$C_{A}$, but that's false and I would like to know why (I guess that has something to do with the passage from three-dimension to two-dimension)

Thanks

Comment: This isn't what you're after, but you might find [Pappus's Centroid Theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PappussCentroidTheorem.html) interesting.

Comment: Yes I knew, it links the centroid of an area with the volume of solid of revolution, but I guess I need a generalization of it, something like http://mathoverflow.net/questions/60416/are-pappus-theorems-generalized