# Derive the centroid of an area from a limiting procedure

Tags: geometry

I wondered if the centroid of an area could be derived as a limit from the centroid of the solid of revolution built by the same area revolving around an axis of revolution.

e.g.: the volume centroid of a spherical wedge is $C_{V} = \frac{3\pi}{16}r\frac{\sin[\theta]}{\theta}$, where $r$ is the radius of the sphere and $\theta$ is the dihedral angle. The centroid of a semicircular lamina is $C_{A} = \frac{4r}{3\pi}$

Now I tought it was possible a limit procedure like $\lim\limits_{\theta\to 0} C_{V}$=$C_{A}$, but that's false and I would like to know why (I guess that has something to do with the passage from three-dimension to two-dimension)

Thanks

Comment: It's because the wedge is thicker on the outside. For the centroid of the volume to match the centroid of the area, the volume should have uniform thickness.

Comment: This question has an [almost exact duplicate](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/435403). Except that that version has additional links, more votes, was created earlier, didn't involve a migration, is associated with an existing user, and on the whole should be preferred over this one here.

Answer (score 0):

I know that if we take a semicylinder the limit pretty obviously will be the same, but I would see mathematically why it doesn't funtion with the spherical wedge